# uWSGI not restarting after being idle

Tags: python, uwsgi, systemd

I'm using uwsgi with systemd on ubuntu 16.

I followed the instructions under one service per app from here: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html

If I start the systemd socket and go to the site, everythings works fine.
But after the idle time (specified in the ini file), the uwsgi process gets killed and further requests don't seem to restart / reactivate the process.

```
workers have been inactive for more than 30 seconds (1501589319-1501589288)
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI.
```

Here's my ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

logto = /tmp/uwsgi.log

master = true
processes = 2
cheap = true
idle = 30
die-on-idle = true

manage-script-name = true
```

This is my systemd socket config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket for uWSGI app

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/uwsgi/myapp.socket
SocketUser=www-data
SocketGroup=www-data
SocketMode=0666

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

And this is my systemd service config:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI app
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/myapp/venv/bin/uwsgi \
        --ini /home/myapp/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini \
        --socket /var/run/uwsgi/myapp.socket
User=www-data
Group=www-data
Restart=on-failure
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
WorkingDirectory=/home/myapp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fiddling around with this for almost a day I've found the answer in the documentation for a related setup. Although it isn't the same kind of setup because I don't use emperor, it did give me a clue of what is going on.

The reason the socket activation only works the first time is because uwsgi overwrites the socket file created by the systemd socket.

See the green "!" Important box on this page:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/OnDemandVassals.html

It says:

> If you will define in your vassal config same socket as used by
>   emperor for on demand action, vassal will override that socket file.
>   That could lead to unexpected behaviour, for example on demand
>   activation of that vassal will work only once.

So in my case I don't have an emperor, but systemd acts like the emperor.

So what is the solution?

Get rid of the `--socket` parameter from the `ExecStart` in the systemd service file.

Instead of having

```
ExecStart=/home/myapp/venv/bin/uwsgi \
        --ini /home/myapp/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini \
        --socket /var/run/uwsgi/myapp.socket
```

I changed it to

```
ExecStart=/home/myapp/venv/bin/uwsgi \
        --ini /home/myapp/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
```

After that I stopped the systemd service and socket, did a `systemctl daemon-reload` and started the systemd socket again. Evrything started working as expected - systemd socket activation works with uwsgi! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi` under `[Service]` which is not in the uWSGI example from the documentation.
This deletes and creates the /var/run/uwsgi (nowadays /run/uwsgi) directory on service restart. As this configuration set up the socket file inside this directory it is deleted on the service restart.

I doubt removing the --socket switch changed anything as uWSGI detects that it was run from systemd and guesses the socket from the systemd socket file. So leaving uwsgi without `--socket` while calling it from a systemd service file with an ad-hoc socket file is the same.

What should have helped is you restarted the systemd socket unit after restarting the systemd service file (the one with RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi) thus the socket was recreated inside the new /run/uwsgi.

A definitive fix is to add `RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=yes` below `RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi` so that the /run/uwsgi directory content (including the socket) is preserved on the systemd service restart or stop.

Or remove `RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi`. But in my case, I add the `--master-fifo` switch to uwsgi pointing to the runtime directory, and with the default permission from the creation of the socket in /run/uwsgi by systemd this directory is only writable by root. Thus the uwsgi user is unable to create the master-fifo. In this case, the option with RuntimeDIrectory with RuntimeDirectoryPreserve is easier.
This master-fifo permission error is:

```
 uwsgi[264019]: uwsgi_master_fifo()/mkfifo(): Permission denied [core/fifo.c line 112]
```